# PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column in 'field list' in

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, prepared-statement

5.6.17 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Generated a simple rountine (stored procedure) in mysql to update a table, which is passed in as a variable.

I have a ugly fix for it, but i want to understand why the first two techniques did not work?

Stored Procedure one could not recognize the table name I passed in

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `setNewCategoryUrlTag`//

CREATE PROCEDURE `setNewCategoryUrlTag`(
    IN _id INT,
    IN _urlid VARCHAR(150),
    IN _tablename VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN
    UPDATE _tablename SET urlid=_urlid WHERE ID=_id;
END//
```

Error was:

```
PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table '_tablename' doesn't exist in
```

So I used the concat function which produced the second error.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `setNewCategoryUrlTag`//

CREATE PROCEDURE `setNewCategoryUrlTag`(
    IN _id INT,
    IN _urlid VARCHAR(150),
    IN _tablename VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN
    set @query = CONCAT('UPDATE ',_tablename,' SET urlid=',_urlid,' WHERE ID=',_id,';');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END//
```

Error was:

```
PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown 'home' column in 'field list' in
```

where home was the actual value of the variable _urlid

The Ugly fix is to add if else statements surrounding updates for specific table names. :(

Thank you for anyone who can explain to me why this error is occuring in my stored procedures. I have used similar techniques before but this never occurred.

**Additional Info**

```
public function dataInsert($category){
    $procedure = "Call setNewCategoryUrlTag(?,?,?)";
    $statement -> bindParam(1, $category['id']);
    $statement -> bindParam(2, $category['urlid']);
    $statement -> bindParam(3, $category['tableName']);
    $statement -> execute();
    echo $category['id']."\t".$category['urlid']."\t".$category['tableName'];
}
```

**Drew's Suggestion?!?!?! (Unsure because his explanation was not clear)**

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `setNewCategoryUrlTag`//
CREATE PROCEDURE `setNewCategoryUrlTag`(
    IN _id INT,
    IN _urlid VARCHAR(150),
    IN _tablename VARCHAR(100)
)
BEGIN
    set @t = _tablename;
    set @var1 = _urlid;
    set @var2 = _id;
    set @query = CONCAT('UPDATE ',@t,' SET urlid=',@var1,' WHERE ID=',@var2,';');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END//
```

Anyhow this produces the same error as my copy.

Comment: @Drew But I don't have a nested procedure? I just want a simple update to occur. The prepared statement also does not work, which baffles me.

Comment: @Drew ok but i still don't see the issue with the dynamic string above. I mean as I have stated the fix I have in place uses logic based upon _tablename and does not use prepared statements. I called the approach ugly. I guess I m a little confused.

Comment: yeah but my prepared statement does not have ? in it. Are you suggesting that I do that the prepared statement that I have above? Please provide a sample of code so I can read it. :)

Comment: Sorry the linked example has a stored procedure created using prepared statement that has ? in the code with @var to be set into the ?. The sample above does not use that technique. So yes I'm having some trouble seeing how that answers my situation.

Comment: If you cannot illustrate for me with relation to my code that is okay. :) I have an ugly answer and it will suffice.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
set @query = CONCAT('UPDATE ',_tablename,' SET urlid=',_urlid,' WHERE ID=',_id,';');
```

would produce this as a query component:

```
CONCAT('UPDATE foo SET urlid=home WHERE ID=42);
                             ^^^^
```

Since `home` isn't quoted, it's interpreted as a field name, which obviously isn't present in your table - so you get a "no such field" error.

You'd need:

```
set @query = CONCAT('UPDATE ',_tablename,' SET urlid=\'',_urlid,'\' WHERE ID=',_id,';');
                                                     ^^---------^^
```

Comment: I will test this out later, because I have moved on. I'm thought maybe it was that, but I referenced numerous other working examples and I never did that. :)

Answer (score 0):

This error might be as a result of at least two possible situations:

1. You are either **looking for a column that does not exist in your table**. Just correct that column probably wrong spelling or the column doesn't exist at all.
2. You are querying the wrong table. Maybe you have the right columns and you them off your head but make sure you are querying the right table. This usually occurs with copy & paste. **Check the name of your table**